# Can't get a way to read the property "title" in class "App\Entity\Travel" triggered by $form->createView()

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, symfony-forms

I am getting the following error on my **symfony** page. Using a CRUD system when I try to edit one item, I fall onto the following error:

> Can't get a way to read the property "title" in class
> "App\Entity\Travel".

My "Travel" entity has no such "title" property as it is not expected. The only place a "title" property is defined is in the TravelTranslation entity, which is in a **ManyToOne** relationship with travel.

After I have commented all references to the form in my twig templates all I find is that the error is triggered by `$form->createView()` in my controller.

```
/**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="travel_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Travel $travel): Response
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $langs = $entityManager->getRepository(Lang::class)->findAll();
        $media = $entityManager->getRepository(Media::class)->findAll();
        $form = $this->createForm(TravelType::class, $travel);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('travel_index');
        }

        return $this->render('crud/travel/edit.html.twig', [
            'langs' => $langs,
            'travel' => $travel,
            'media' => $media,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

But then my TravelType form contains the following code:

```
class TravelType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('main_title')
            ->add('category', EntityType::class,[
                'class' => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                                ->andWhere('c.type = :type')
                                                ->setParameter('type', 'country')
                                                ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
                },
            ])
            ->add('price_driver', MoneyType::class,[
                'divisor' => 100,
            ])
            ->add('price_codriver', MoneyType::class,[
                'divisor' => 100,
            ])
           /*  ->add('country') */
            ->add('km')
            ->add('media', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Media::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true
            ])
            ->add('status')
            ->add('duration')
            ->add('level')
            ->add('travelTranslations', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => TravelTranslationType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false
                ],
                'by_reference' => false,
                // this allows the creation of new forms and the prototype too
                'allow_add' => true,
                // self explanatory, this one allows the form to be removed
                'allow_delete' => true
            ])
            ->add('dates', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => DatesType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false
                ],
                'by_reference' => false,
                // this allows the creation of new forms and the prototype too
                'allow_add' => true,
                // self explanatory, this one allows the form to be removed
                'allow_delete' => true
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Travel::class,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the error by getting into the DatesType::class (a custom entity type form not DateType) and fixing it as it was the one getting with the trouble of referring to the wrong property "title" in a collection type

By changing

```
 ->add('travel', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Travel::class,
                'choice_label' => 'title'
            ] )
```

By:

```
 ->add('travel', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Travel::class,
                'choice_label' => 'main_title'
            ] )
```

Where main_title is the real property.